# How to report scores for a game center leaderboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How exactly do you create a scoring system that you can report to a leaderboard on game center, and how do you report it?

Can you simply make a simple scoring system, and use NSUserDefaults to post the highest score to a leaderboard?

How do you get the leaderboard to appear if so?

Comment: How is this question different from the previous one?

Comment: You should not store the high score on `NSUserDefaults`. At least, not without an encryption. It's very easy for the user to change it.

Comment: If you actually take the time to read @ElTomato its completely different. In the fist one I'm actually asking how to integrate it all together, which was solved. Now I'm asking a completely different question, open your eyes.

Comment: Really the user can change it!? @Gonzo???

Comment: Unfortnently yes. But there are a lot of workarounds. This post talks about it, http://www.andyibanez.com/nsuserdefaults-not-for-sensitive-data/

Comment: Have you played with ```GKAchievement```? May be this can give you and idea after you read its documentation - ```[GKAchievement reportAchievements:scoreArray withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)```